# About Heat Equation and Maximum Principle

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I can not prove the following problem.

In area $\Omega$, we have $v\in C^2(\Omega\times[T,\infty))\bigcup C^1(\partial\Omega\times[T,\infty))$ satisfy the following equation:

> $$\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}-\Delta v \leq \alpha -v$$
>    and 
>   $$\frac{\partial v}{\partial n}=0,\ v(x,0)=v_0(x)$$

Prove that ${\rm lim}_{t_0\rightarrow \infty}{\rm sup}_{t\geq t_0}v(x,t)\leq \alpha$

I have try to use Proofs by Contradiction but I can only proof that if the consequence is wrong, the maximal of $v$ will not be attain in the inner of area. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If $v(x,t) \leq \alpha$ for all $t< t_0$ and if $v(x_0,t_0)=\alpha$ then $$ \Delta v (x_0,t_0)\leq 0 $$ so that $$\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} (x_0,t_0)\leq \Delta v(x_0,t_0)+  \alpha - v(x_0,t_0) =\Delta v(x_0,t_0)\leq 0 $$

Comment: we can only prove that $\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}\geq 0$, we can not get $\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}> 0$, And if the maximal is in boundary, we cannot get anything from the $\Delta v$

Comment: I corrected. If at $(x_0,_0)$ $v$ has value $\alpha$ then it cannot increase more wrt time $t$.